# NodeJS Async / Await - Build configuration file with API call

Tags: node.js, async-await, configuration-files

I would like to have a configuration file with variables set with data I fetch from an API.

I think I must use `async` and `await` features to do so, otherwise my variable would stay undefined.

But I don't know how to integrate this and keep the node `exports.myVariable = myData` available within an `async function` ?

Below is the code I tried to write to do so (all in the same file) :

```js
const fetchAPI = function(jsonQuery) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var reqOptions = {
            headers: apiHeaders,
            json:jsonQuery,
        }

        request.post(apiURL, function (error, res, body) {
            if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
                resolve(body);
            } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

```js
var wallsData = {}
const fetchWalls = async function (){

    var jsonQuery = [{ "recordType": "page","query": "pageTemplate = 1011"}]

    let body = await utils.fetchAPI(jsonQuery)

    let pageList = await body[0].dataHashes
    for(i=0;i<pageList.length;i++){
        var page = pageList[i]
        wallsData[page.title.fr] = [page.difficultyList,page.wallType]
    }
    return wallsData
    throw new Error("WOOPS")
}

try{

    const wallsData = fetchWalls()
    console.log(wallsData)
    exports.wallsData = wallsData

}catch(err){
    console.log(err)
}
```

The output of `console.log(wallsData)` shows `Promise { <pending> }`, therefore it is not resolved and the configuration file keep being executed without the data in wallsData...

What do I miss ?

Thanks,
Cheers

Comment: You must `await` the `fetchWalls()` cause is an async function, so a promise

Comment: Basically you should export `fetchWalls`, not the final value. From another module when you require this one, it imediatly start to execute. It's a better practice to require the module and then manually manage the fetchWalls function.

Comment: I highely doubt that your `body[0].dataHashes` is a promise, so you do not need to await it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A promise is a special object that either succeeds with a result or fails with a rejection. The async-await-syntax is syntactic sugar to help to deal with promises.

If you define a function as aync it *always* will return a promise.

Even a function like that reads like

```
const foo = async() => {
     return "hello";
}
```

returns a promise of a string, not only a string. And you need to wait until it's been resolved or rejected.

It's analogue to:

```
const foo = async() => {
     return Promise.resolve("Hello");
}
```

or:

```
const foo = async() => {
     return new Promise(resolve => resolve("Hello"));
}
```

Your `fetchWalls` similarly is a promise that will remain pending for a time. You'll have to make sure it either succeeds or fails by setting up the `then` or `catch` handlers in your outer scope:

```
fetchWalls()
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

The outer scope is never async, so you cannot use await there. You can only use await inside other async functions.

I would also not use your try-catch for that outer scope promise handling. I think you are confusing the try-catch approach that is intended to be used *within* async functions, as there it helps to avoid nesting and reads like synchronous code:

E.g. you could do inside your `fetchWalls` defintion:

```
const fetchWalls = async function (){
    var jsonQuery = [{ "recordType": "page","query": "pageTemplate = 1011"}]

    try {
        let body = await utils.fetchAPI(jsonQuery)
    } catch(e) {
         // e is the reason of the promise rejection if you want to decide what to do based on it. If you would not catch it, the rejection would chain through to the first error handler.
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this precise answer, it helped me out to understand the concept of promises and async function. I followed your tips, and got it working !

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the statements like,

```
try{

    const wallsData = fetchWalls();
    wallsData.then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    });
    exports.wallsData = wallsData; // when importing in other file this returns as promise and we should use async/await to handle this.

}catch(err){


  console.log(err)
}
```