# asnyc function for retrieving Google Secret Manager Variable returns promise pending

Tags: javascript, express, async-await, google-secret-manager

I am trying to switch my environment variables to Google Secrets Manager, but I am encountering a problem. I am running an expressjs api trying to establish a database connection. But whatever I try, it only returns `Promise { <pending> }` instead of waiting for the async function to finish. Any help is highly appreciated!

gcloud.js

```
const { SecretManagerServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager');
const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();

async function getSecret(name) {

const name = `projects/PROJECT-ID/secrets/${name}/versions/latest`;

const [version] = await client.accessSecretVersion({
  name: name,
});

const payload = version.payload.data.toString();

return payload;
}

module.exports.getSecret = getSecret;
```

config.js

```
const gcloud = require('./config/gcloud.js')

const config = {
  authSecret: gcloud.getSecret(SECRET_NAME)
}

module.exports = config
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` the result of `gcloud.getSecret`:

```
// Not actually valid
const config = {
  authSecret: await gcloud.getSecret(SECRET_NAME)
}
```

However, top-level await isn't widely supported yet, so you'll need to build the config inside a function: [NodeJS Async / Await - Build configuration file with API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491580/nodejs-async-await-build-configuration-file-with-api-call)

Comment: I tried "await" the result of gloud.getSecret - however it did not change the result.

Comment: Right, that's because top-level await isn't widely supported. See the other link I posted.

Comment: I just don’t seem to get it to work... would you be able to give me a code example?